# script stdout comparison in Python

Tags: python

I have a program which tries to use the output of another script to decide what to do.

I take in the `stdout` of a Python process from an SSH session, the output of which is either `"Verified"` or `"Unverified"`, which appears on the command line when I print it as `['Verified\n']`.

My code is below. First I read in the output, then print it, then try to compare it. However it always comes out as the second option, that a does not equal verified - even when it should. Perhaps there is something I am missing about `stdout`, but I have tried many variations of the `(if a == )` condition, including with the brackets I listed above. I'm not sure why it doesn't work at all.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("python verify.py")

a = stdout.readlines()
print a

if (a == "Verified"):
    print ("a does equal verified")
else:
    print ("a does not equal verified")
```

Comment: Please.. no parentheses around conditions unless you need them e.g. due to line wrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readlines()` returns a list and as you pointed out it returns with the `\n`

Have you tried this?:

```
if(len(a) and a[0] == "Verified\n"):
  # verfiied, do your stuff here
```

Comment: Use `a` instead of `len(a)` and please get rid of the parentheses around the condition.